# How to determine the magnitude of an eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-modeling

The question asks me to give the magnitude of my first eigenvalue at a point.  I have been given a point (100, 0) and I calculated the eigenvalues as, eigenvalue1 = -0.38456 and eigenvalue2 = -0.023567.  How is magnitude of each eigenvalue determined?.

Comment: Isn't the magnitude of a given number just its absolute value?

Comment: Ha, that's what I thought, but thought they were trying to trick me.  Which they did I guess!

Comment: Why not answer your own question, then? You might get some upvotes.